# DataDog APM Java library shows a generic java-aws-sdk service: how do I visualize specific AWS services instead?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, trace, datadog, apm

I have instrumented a Java application with the DataDog APM library (`dd-java-agent.jar`) as per their documentation, adding the usual `DD_ENV`, `DD_SERVICE`, `DD_VERSION` env vars.

The application runs on EKS and interacts with S3 and RDS via the AWS Java SDK library.

In the APM console of the DataDog Web UI I see my application as a separate service.
The additional service `java-aws-sdk` is automatically identified as a separate service to which my app makes calls.

I would like specific AWS services such as S3 appear as separate services as well.

I have read the the [DataDog tracing documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/trace_collection/library_config/java/) multiple times but haven't found anything specific to my use case besides the usual service monitoring configuration.

One thing I admittedly did not try is tagging the code with custom traces where it calls AWS services, such as S3. I would like to avoid this approach though, and instead find a general way to visualize the interaction with specific AWS services through configuration rather than having to tag every specific AWS interaction in the code.

Answer (score 0):

One important detail to notice is that the Service Map will only show connection between services if there has been traffic during the (short) timespan currently selected.

After submitting 1k requests to the Java app involving access to the database, the Service Map did indeed show a direct connection between the app and the db.

Still not sure what the java-aws-sdk is about tho:

[image: java app with db instrumented with datadog apm]

"java-aws-sdk" seems to come from the tracing library

https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-java/blob/master/dd-java-agent/instrumentation/aws-java-sdk-1.11.0/src/main/java/datadog/trace/instrumentation/aws/v0/AwsSdkClientDecorator.java#L29

Answer (score 0):

DataDog services can be renamed using the service mapping configuration variable:

https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/trace_collection/library_config/java/